# remove iframe if the src value is null (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

im looking to show or not show an iframe based on if certain data has a url value assigned to it or not. If the data does not have a value aka is null i want to use ng-if to remove the iframe entirely. below is the current code i have trying to do this:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in names | orderBy: '-id'" >
    {{post.title}}<br>
    {{post.pBody}}<br>
    {{post.category}}<br>
    <iframe ng-if="post.url != 'null'" ng-src="{{myUrl}}" height=250 width=750></iframe><br><br>
</li>
```

Is there any reason why this isnt working. currently when i set myUrl to null it just displays an empty iframe which is not what i desire.

currently for testing purposes i have myUrl set as so: $scope.myUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(null);

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you want:

```
<iframe ng-if="!!post.url" ng-src="{{myUrl}}">
```